# Why can't files be renamed by using F2 on the open files dialog screen?

Tags: gnome, gtk, files

Why is it not possible to edit file names in the **open file** window dialogues? For instance, by pressing F2 (as per example on LibreOffice open document window dialogue).

This is very useful and Windows has does this for a long time (it's just necessary to select one file and press F2... )  Gnome just allows this on the desktop and Nautilus windows (why these windows are not based on Nautilus?)

Answer (score 6):

This is a very old [bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=325150) in Gnome. In the past it has seemed that the Gnome/GTK developers believe users should just use their File Manager to manage files and use the "file-chooser" to choose files for opening or saving, but not renaming or deleting.

Perhaps the developers can be convinced otherwise.

Comment: _"Perhaps the developers can be convinced otherwise."_ -- No luck so far.